# Fill out missing time series intervals

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo, lubridate

I have several time intervals recorded as the following:

```
  In         Out          tag      
  2008-12-18 2008-12-19   1
  2008-12-22 2008-12-23   1
  2008-12-29 2009-01-02   1
  2009-01-05 2009-01-05   1
  2009-01-13 2009-01-13   1
  2009-01-14 2009-01-14   1
  2009-01-19 2009-01-19   1
```

I would like to fill inn the missing intervals so it looks like this:

```
  In         Out          tag      
  2008-12-18 2008-12-19   1
  2008-12-20 2008-12-21   0
  2008-12-22 2008-12-23   1
  2008-12-24 2008-12-28   0
  2008-12-29 2009-01-02   1
  2009-01-03 2008-01-04   0
  2009-01-05 2009-01-05   1
  ...
```

I know that I can use `zoo` to fill out missing dates of a time series. Also that I could create intervals with `interval(start, end)` from the `lubridate` package. My initial though was that I somehow could combine this to fill out the missing intervals.

I've also been thinking about whether there are any "brut-force" methods that I could use to fill the intervals. e.g., function that would get the last item of `Out` in the previous row and `In` from the next row, but have not managed to find any solution.

Ideally, I would like to know if there are any clever ways to do this using `zoo`, `lubridate`, `xts` or other tools in R?

Comment: The days difference in 'In' and 'Out' is not following any patterns or is there any patterns? For example, in the fourth row, both In and Out are in '2009-01-05'.  So, how de we know what will be next starting point and whether the difference in 'In' and 'Out' are single day or same day?

Comment: row 4 from your 2nd df is 24 - 28. Why not 24-25, 26-27...?

Comment: There are no patterns in what intervals are missing.

Comment: I would not like to split the intervals into one-day intervals (e.g., 24-28 to 24-25, 26-27 etc.) This would expand the dataset unnecessary and be impractical for the further analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(data.table)

df = data.table(
  In=as.Date('2008-12-18') + cumsum(c(0,4,7,7,8,1,5)),
  Out=as.Date('2008-12-19') + cumsum(c(0,4,10,3,8,1,5)),
  tag=1)

toMerge = df[, .(In=Out+1, Out=shift(In-1, type='lead'), tag=0)][In <= Out]

> merge(df, toMerge, all=T)
#            In        Out tag
# 1: 2008-12-18 2008-12-19   1
# 2: 2008-12-20 2008-12-21   0
# 3: 2008-12-22 2008-12-23   1
# 4: 2008-12-24 2008-12-28   0
# 5: 2008-12-29 2009-01-02   1
# 6: 2009-01-03 2009-01-04   0
# ...
```

Comment: Did not get the merge to work, but used rbind. Great with the data.table solution where it is easy to include a by-statement.